# PHP Use thread safe or not

Tags: php, windows, multithreading

I am building a web server install for a production server on a windows 2008 R2 64 bit server

I have installed Apache 2.4 64 bit and that is working fine

Next step, PHP

I have read about the differences between thread safe and not but just cant seem to grasp which I should be using (and why).

Can anybody confirm which PHP Install I should use with my current setup?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[You should look at the PHP docs:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.obtaining.php#faq.obtaining.threadsafety)

> Thread Safety means that binary can work in a multithreaded webserver context, such as Apache 2 on Windows. Thread Safety works by creating a local storage copy in each thread, so that the data won't collide with another thread.
>
> So what do I choose? If you choose to run PHP as a CGI binary, then you won't need thread safety, because the binary is invoked at each request. For multithreaded webservers, such as IIS5 and IIS6, you should use the threaded version of PHP.

So for example, if you use `FastCGI` with Apache, go for the non-thread safe, and if you use LoadModule, go for the thread-safe version.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the feedback, but I am using Apache 2.4 on Windows 2008 64 bit server. So does that require thread safe or not? I did read all th einfo about the technical differences but they all seem to fall short of a final say in what to use

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? FastCGI uses several PHP threads for a PHP process, so PHP needs to be thread-safe, whereas with mod_php prefork the Apache requests are forked so there's no need for thread-safety as there's only one thread per process anyway.

Comment: What if you use PHP built-in web server? Which variant of PHP to use for optimal performance?

Answer (score 4):

"With Apache you have to use the Thread Safe (TS) versions of PHP." from the download page if anyone else is ever looking.